# Isolating an image from a layered picture online

Tags: layers

So I found this image that I really like, and I want to isolate the individual components of the picture into individual images. How would I isolate each individual component?
[image]

Comment: Have you bought this image (or you have subscription)?

Comment: You would buy the vector image and delete the vectors on top. However... There are reasons this may not work. Its normal to see beginners buy stick art only to realize its not fit for your purpose because the transparency is flattened etc etc.

Comment: @Carolina it's a vector actually. You'll need to buy it you have option to select layers individually.'

Comment: Sounds good! Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: It may be easier to just find a vector image of the building you *do* want. It's not like these are rare structures.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this. But again I would advice caution here. There is absolutely no guarantee that the vector image is in a form that makes this easy. In fact the standard procedures in shutterstock may be a bit counterproductive for what you ask.

It is far better to search for an image that does what you ask out of the box. This is safer and most likely its available. There are a lot of post on this site that attest to this.

But yeah one can delete the offending vector objects if you want.